# LIFERAY 6.2 Pagination --- Can I Set Current Page From Inside JSP?

Tags: jsp, pagination, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I know I can set current page of my search container's pagination using an URL parameter (e.g. `&cur=2`).

However, I want to do this from inside the JSP: just like I can set the delta in `<liferay-ui:search-container delta=5>`.

Is this possible? Where is the parameter `cur` from the URL passed to? I've searched sources to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `cur` in `search container` as follow:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>

    Integer cur = (Integer)request.getAttribute("cur");        
        if(cur == null){
            cur = 1;
        }
```

......

```
    <%        portletURL.setParameter("cur", String.valueOf(cur));  
      searchContainer.setIteratorURL(portletURL);    %>

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```